# django string index out of range in template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create from with MultipleChoiceFields and I get very weird error.

Here's my forms.py:

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(FilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cities'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                                          choices=self.get_cities())
        self.fields['law_areas'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                                             choices=self.get_law_areas())

    lawyer_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    def get_cities(self):
        cities_queryset = []
        for lawyer in User.objects.all():
            if lawyer.city not in cities_queryset:
                cities_queryset.append(lawyer.city)

        return cities_queryset

    def get_law_areas(self):
        return LawArea.objects.all()
```

Here's my views.py:

```
def lawyers(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        pass
    else:
        form = FilterForm()

        return render(request, "lawyer_directory_v2.html", {"form": form})
```

And finally I try to use my form in the template:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

And on this exact line the error comes up:

```
IndexError at /lawyers/
string index out of range
```

I have no idea how to debug this or what might be wrong. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: You need to show the whole traceback, not just the error message. It will tell us exactly which line is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `get_cities` method is returning a list of strings. But a ChoiceField expects a list of tuples in the form (id, readable_value).

Answer (score 0):

That kind of errors normally comes from a missing data in the database.

Maybe some User doesn't have a city?